# How to get Android custom adapter element position

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

How to retrieve position of an element from a custom adapter based on element name.. I have a cityAdapter that contains city name and id in key value format. I am trying to retrieve position by the following code

```
SpinnerModel model=new SpinnerModel();
            model.setKey(""+currentLocation);
            model.setValue(currentLocationValue);
            int position = cityAdapter.getPosition(model);
```

Position is returning as -1.
Can any one please guide me how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get position of a particular item on click of a list,
is there any particular reason so that you don't want to get item position on list click?

Comment: The error was somewhere else I fixed the same. Thanks for your response